# Collection Document Id in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, observablecollection

How I get the generated document ID of a collection in Firestore?

[image: Screenshot of collections and IDs]

Comment: Do you want to get the existing doc id or do you want to get the doc id when you insert a new document?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the id of a Firestore doc, call `doc.id`. This is not in `doc.data` and confused me as well.

```js
const docs = await getDocs(collection(db, 'collection_name'));
docs.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id);
});
```